# How to use multiple expect in jasmine

Tags: unit-testing, bdd, jasmine

I am using jasmine with `jasmine-species` . I am making a test of search in my site . 
In search there are multiple criteria a user can select . I want to know that how to expect with multiple criteria.

Suppose this is my case

```
expect(variable1).toEqual('');
expect(variable2).toEqual('');
expect(variable3).toEqual('');
expect(variable4).toEqual('');
```

My question is that i want to move all expects into single expect . Is this possible in jasmine ? if yes , then how ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 24, accepted):

expect(variable1 == 1 && variable2 == 2).toBeTruthy();

Comment: So straightforward, easy to sometimes lose oneself in the API you forget to actually solve the problem with the language!